# Properties in Model.json

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

What are the properties that can be mentioned in the Model.json file of a model in loopback(Strongloop) ?

I was trying to figure out what extra properties can be added to the model.json file but in the documentation very less is given.

Answer (score 0):

Certain new fields like – hidden, hiddenProperties, hiddenAPIProperties can be added to the model.json file which are not mentioned in the Loopback documentation……take a look at these

```
{
  "name": "product",
  "plural": "products",
  "base": "persistedModel",
 "strict": true,
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "text",
      "required": true,
      "access": "readOnly",
      "readOnlyType": "auto"
    },
    "created": {
      "type": "text",
      "required": true,
      "access": "readOnly",
      "readOnlyType": "createdTimestamp"
    },
    "lastUpdated": {
      "type": "text",
      "required": true,
      "access": "readOnly",
      "readOnlyType": "updatedTimestamp"
    },
    "requestIPAddress": {
      "type": "text",
      "required": true,
      "access": "hidden"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "required": true,
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "text",
      "required": true
    },
    "manufacturerId": {
      "required": true
    },
    "supplierId": {
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "hidden": [],
  "hiddenProperties": [],
  "hiddenAPIProperties": [],
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "manufacturer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "manufacturer",
      "foreignKey": "manufacturerId"
    },
    "supplier": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "supplier",
      "foreignKey": "supplierId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [   
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "modelProperty": "manufacturerId"
      "permission": "DENY",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "modelProperty": "supplierId"
      "permission": "DENY",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone"
    },
    {
      "property": "_READ_HIDDEN_PROPERTIES_",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin"
    },
    {
      "property": "_WRITE_HIDDEN_PROPERTIES_",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "modelProperty": "manufacturerId"
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "modelProperty": "supplierId"
      "permission": "ALLOW",
     "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "modelProperty": "manufacturerId"
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "productAdmin"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "modelProperty": "supplierId"
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "productAdmin"
    }
  ],
  "methods": []
}
```